# Is possible to save a queryset in db in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to save the result of this query:
`foo = WordCount.objects.filter(lesson__course=course).values('lesson__course', 'word').annotate(totWords=Sum('count'))`

which results in a queryset consisting of 'word', 'course' and 'totWords'

I have a model with those fields and i need to save foo in it.

It si possible only with a for loop or there is a clever way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Supposed you have a `Foo` django model, with `word`, `course` and `totWords` fields.

You can do something like that:

```py
queryset = WordCount.objects.filter(lesson__course=course).values('lesson__course', 'word').annotate(totWords=Sum('count')))
foo_list = Foo.objects.bulk_create(map(lambda el: Foo(**el), queryset))
```